# Additional conditions in ternary operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ternary-operator

I want to show the component based on the state value. My

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import One from './One'
import Two from './Two'
import Three from './Three'

class MyTest extends Component{

    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          slide: 1
        }
      }

    handleClick=()=>{
        const counter=this.state.slide;
        this.setState({
                slide:counter+1
        })
    }

render(){
    return (
             <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
                {this.state.slide===1 ? <One /> : 
                   {this.state.slide===2 ? <Two /> : <Three /> } }
             </div>     
           )
    }

}

export default MyTest;
```

I get the error: for `{this.state.slide===2` `Parsing error: Unexpected keyword 'this'`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a note. Am assuming you want your ```handleclick()``` to cycle slide 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,... If so, then your ```handleclick()``` logic seems to increment ```slide``` indefinitely. i.e 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,.. . If am thinking right, you may want to take a look at my ```handleclick()``` [logic in my answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836403/additional-conditions-in-ternary-operator/57836547#answer-57836547)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no need of `{ and }` inside internal ternary

```
{this.state.slide===1 ? <One /> : 
                   this.state.slide===2 ? <Two /> : <Three /> }
```

Comment: I totally forgot that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note. Am assuming you want your `handleclick()` to cycle `this.state.slide`. i.e 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,... If so, then your `handleclick()` logic seems to increment `this.state.slide` indefinitely. i.e 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,.. . If am thinking right, you may want to change the logic in your `handleclick()` method.

Try this, hope it helps

```
handleClick = () => {
  const counter = this.state.slide;
  if (counter == 3) {
    this.setState({
      slide: 1
    });
  } else if (counter <= 2) {
    this.setState({
      slide: counter + 1
    });
  }
}
```